# Programs doesn't add more than one Node to the tree. Searching comes Up with only one node info

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


class Student_Node{
public:
    Student_Node *right,*left;
    int ID;
    string First_Name;
    int Age;
    float Test_Score,CGPA;

};

class Student_Tree{
Student_Node *root;

public:
    Student_Tree()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
    void take_input();
    void build_tree(int id,string name,int age,float score,float cgpa);
    void BST_search();
    void input_sort(Student_Node *n, Student_Node *r);
    void Search (int id);
    void searching(int id,Student_Node *r);
    void Node_Depth(int id);
    void FindHeight();
    int Height(Student_Node* root);
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

This is my build function. In `take_input()` i apply a loop to give the user choice to add as many nodes as he wants. In the loop the user gives data which is passed the `obj.build_tree(int id,string name,int age,float score,float cgpa);` But it adds only one Node and nothing more. When i call my `Search (int id)` it only outputs the data of first node.

```
 void Student_Tree::build_tree(int id,string name,int age,float score,float 
  cgpa)
  {
  Student_Node *n= new Student_Node(); 
    n->ID=id;
  n->First_Name=name;
 n->Age=age;
 n->CGPA=cgpa;
 n->Test_Score=score;
 if(root==NULL)
 {
    root=n;
 }
 else
 {
    input_sort(n,root);
 }
 }

void Student_Tree::input_sort(Student_Node *n, Student_Node *r)
{
if(r->ID>=n->ID)
{
    if(r->left!=NULL)
    {
        input_sort(n,r->left);
    }
    else
    {
        n=r->left;
    }
}

if(r->ID<=n->ID)
{
    if(r->right!=NULL)
    {
        input_sort(n,r->right);
    }
    else
    {
        n=r->right;
    }
    }
}



/////// inout takes input from user, then sends it to the build fucntion
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Student_Tree::Search (int id)
{
Student_Node *n=new Student_Node();
n=root;
if(n==NULL)
{
    cout<<"Tree is empty"<<endl;
}
else 
{
    searching(id,root);
}
}
void Student_Tree::searching(int id,Student_Node *r)
{
if(r->ID>=id)
{
    if(r->ID==id)
    {
        cout<<"ID"<<" "<<"Age"<<" "<<"CGPA"<<" "<<"First Name"<<" "<<"Test 
Score"<<endl;
        cout<<"------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------"<<endl;
        cout<<r->ID<<" "<<r->Age<<" "<<r->CGPA<<" "<<r->First_Name<<" "<<r-> 
Test_Score;
    }
    else
    {
        searching(id,r->left);
    }
}
else if(r->ID<=id)
{
    if(r->ID==id)
    {
        cout<<r->ID;
    }
    else
    {
        searching(id,r->right);
    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"Roll No Not found"<<endl;
   } 
}

void Student_Tree::FindHeight()
{
Height(root);
}

 int Student_Tree::Height(Student_Node *r)
{  
if(r==NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

else
{
    int lb=Height(r->left);
    int rb=Height(r->right);
    cout<<max(lb,rb)+1;
    return max(lb,rb)+1;
}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Student_Tree::Node_Depth(int id) 
{
int depth = 0;
Student_Node *temp = new Student_Node;
temp = root;
// Run the loop untill temp points to a NULL pointer.
while(temp != NULL)
{
    depth++;
    if(temp->ID == id)
    {
        cout<<"\nData found at depth: "<<depth<<endl;
        return;
    }
    // Shift pointer to left child.
    else if(temp->ID > id)
        temp = temp->left;
    // Shift pointer to right child.
    else
        temp = temp->right;
}

cout<<"\n Data not found";
return;
}



void take_input()
{
Student_Tree obj;   
    int ID;
    string First_Name;
    int Age;
    float Test_Score,CGPA;
    cout<<"How many students data do you want to enter?"<<endl;
    int no; cin>>no;
    for(int i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tEnter Student Id"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t";cin>>ID;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tEnter Student First Name"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t";cin>>First_Name;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tEnter Student Age"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t";cin>>Age;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tTest Student Score"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t";cin>>Test_Score;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\tEnter Student CGPA"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t";cin>>CGPA;     
    obj.build_tree(ID,First_Name,Age,Test_Score,CGPA);
    }
}
int main()
{
Student_Tree obj;
take_input();
cout<<"Enter node"<<endl;
int n; cin>>n;
obj.Node_Depth(n);
obj.FindHeight();
cout<<"\nEnter id to search"<<endl; int id; cin>>id;
obj.Search(id);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I am not sure why you have `n=r->left;` and `n=r->right;` in `input_sort()` they don't really accomplish anything. You are setting the local pointer `n` to a nullptr. I think you wanted `r->left = n;` and `r->right = n` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `build_tree` function calls `input_sort` to add an additional node. But `input_sort` never adds anything to anything else. What code do you think actually attaches a second node into the tree? There doesn't seem to be any.

```
 if(root==NULL)
 {
    root=n;
 }
 else
 {
    input_sort(n,root);
 }
```

The first part of this code adds `n` to the tree if the tree is empty. The second part is expected to add `n` to the three if the tree is not empty.

```
void Student_Tree::input_sort(Student_Node *n, Student_Node *r)
{
    if(r->ID>=n->ID)
    {
        if(r->left!=NULL)
        {
            input_sort(n,r->left);
        }
        else
        {
            n=r->left;
```

We're already hosed right here. This function was called with `n` being the new node to be added and no other pointer to that node was stored anywhere. If we change the value of `n` here, we lose the only pointer we had to the node we were supposed to add.

Even if we don't get hosed here, there's no code in `input_sort` anywhere to actually add a node to the tree, and `build_tree` is expecting it to.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do to add another node to the tree

Comment: Change `n=r->left;` to `r->left = n;` do the same for the right.